# Estimating fog incidence based on ocean temperature

Tags: meteorology, ocean, temperature

In the tropics, say the Caribbean, I have read that there is very often a lot of nighttime and morning fog. I have read that the crucial factors are

1. The ocean temperature
2. Cool nighttime air temperatures
3. The movement of air from areas above land to areas above the sea

Assuming this is more or less correct, I am wondering if there is any way to estimate the effect of a local rise in sea temperature, say by 1°C.

My guess is that you'll get more fog lasting later, but I don't really know what I'm talking about.

Note: if I have incorrectly described the issues at stake, I would be pleased to be corrected.

Comment: "relatively dry air" in the Caribbean? Not an expert in any way shape or form, but my guess would be that the air from over the water would be pretty humid. (Are you talking about fog over land, or over sea?)

Comment: @DanielGriscom I've read that the fog is thickest where there is a certain amount of arid air over the land which meets the very moist air over the sea. But my source could be completely wrong about that.

Comment: I was under the impression that, by definition, fog meant that the air was super-saturated with water, meaning the measured humidity would be right around 100%: in other words when the air temperature falls to the dew point (maybe that's what you mean by "Cool nighttime air temperatures"?). Could you tell us more about your source?

Comment: I'm afraid my sources are wildly varied and not especially reliable, ranging from various Wikipedia articles to a lengthy "suggestions for people moving to the tropics" article.

Comment: I have edited what is now factor #3 to reflect what appears to be misinformation or misunderstanding on my part.

Comment: For #3, wouldn't it be movement of humid air from the sea (which is also warmer at night because sea temperature changes less than land temperature) moving to land (where the temperature is lower, causing the humid air from the sea to condense into fog) instead?

Comment: @BarryCarter: I don't know. Would it? Would that make the question more answerable? As I say, I really don't understand much about meteorology.